# DataTrigger to make WPF Button inactive until TextBox has value

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I want the `Button` control's property to be `IsEnabled="False"` until a value is entered into a `TextBox` in the `Window`.

**Code so far:**

```
<Button
  Content="Click Me"
  Name="ClickMe"
  VerticalAlignment="Top"
  Click="ClickMe_Click">
  <Button.Style>
    <Style>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
          Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Length}"
          <!-- or even: Binding="{Binding Path=textBox.Length}" -->
          Value="0">
          <Setter
            Property="Button.IsEnabled"
            Value="false" />
          </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Also, is it possible to have this `Button` control's `IsEnabled` property be based on 3 different `TextBox` controls all having values?

Comment: Oops, I had already tried `Binding="{Binding ViewModelDataMember}" Value=""`, but `Value="{x:Null}"` was the key here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are employing a presentation model, such as a ViewModel, you should bind directly the data instead of the UI elements.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding MiddleName}" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding LastName}" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

That said, if you are using a presentation model, you can always add a `bool` "EnableSave" property and handle all the presentation logic there instead of in the view itself.

#### update

As can be seen by following the comments, I mistakenly set this up to enable the `Button` when *any* `TextBox` has a value, but the requirement is that the `Button` be enabled when *all* `TextBox`es have values.

Conceptually, all you have to do is reverse the conditions -- instead of "false if all conditions false," we want "true if all conditions true."

The catch is that there is no way to say "not null" in the XAML -- no way without an `IValueConverter`, that is. I'd create a `NullToBoolConverter` that returns `false` for `null` and `true` for `!= null`.

Given such a converter:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Binding="{Binding FirstName,
                Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}}" Value="True" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding MiddleName,
                Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}}" Value="True" />
            <Condition Binding="{Binding LastName,
                Converter={StaticResource NullToBoolConverter}}" Value="True" />
        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: `{x:Null}` fixed my code! (for one data member) *I do have a ViewModel, and in my real code I was binding to the data.*  But `<MultiDataTrigger>` = **THANKS!**

Comment: *However,* needed to make it `Property="Button.IsEnabled"`

Comment: @JohnB You can also specify that it is a `Button` style by declaring it with `<Style TargetType="Button">`.

Comment: FYI, I have to click on another `TextBox` after by final 3rd data member gets set, before the `Button` will wake up.  Also, the button doesn't seem to go inactive when I clear a data member (setting value to `null`).  Lastly, and you'll never believe this one, *my speakers generate a high frequency hum when I display data* in my `DataGrid` - if I minimize the app, or clear the data, the hum goes away! :o

Comment: @JohnB Try adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` *in the binding*. The default for a `TextBox` is `LostFocus`. When you clear the text, you are probably setting the value to an empty string rather than `null`. You can use a converter to handle both cases, or add logic to the setter of the view-model that sets the value to `null` when `value == string.Empty`. And as for the datagrid and your speakers… well, I don't know. You could try asking on SuperUser.com.

Comment: @Jay: I did that (even figured out how to do it through Properties dialog), but now the `Button` becomes active even when the 1st `TextBox` gets a value.  Also, I am pretty sure I'm using `null`.  The speakers thing is probably from high radiation!  That's the trade-off for using WPF.

Comment: @JohnB Sorry, I lost track of the requirement -- I thought it was supposed to be enabled when any of the textboxes have values. I'll update the answer to match the requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  `Button` is disabled at program startup.  I set a breakpoint in the `IValueConverter`, and it seems to get called correctly, and return the appropriate value.  However, the `Button` gets enabled after only one condition is `true`. My converter works fine for *"false if all conditions false,"* but not for the opposite :(

Answer (score 3):

`TextBox` doesn't have a `Length` property. Setting your binding Path to `Text.Length` might work.

But a more-flexible solution would be to use a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx), which can return true or false based on the value of the string passed into it. You can then bind to the TextBox's Text property, like so:

In your control's Resources:

```
<localNamespace:MyEmptyStringToBooleanValueConverter x:Key="myValueConverter"/>
```

Your DataTrigger definition then looks like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=Text, 
                               Converter={StaticResource myValueConverter}}"   
             Value="False">
```

As for your second request, you can use a [MultiBinding](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings). In this case, you *must* use a value converter to define how the results of the binding should be interpreted. See the linked tutorial for details.

Comment: +1, thanks, but `<MultiDataTrigger>` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The part you mentioned about Text.Length worked like a charm for me.  `<CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=txtBox, Path=Text.Length}/>`

Answer (score 2):

Using property x:Name="FirstName" and similarly for others following code will work to enable the button when the data is present in all the fields.

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=FirstName,Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MiddleName,Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}"  Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LastName,Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>                  
         </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
 </Button.Style>
```